# D3 calendar view using json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want do this calendar in d3js but I want to make it work with json.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

I have this json:

```
[{
 "category": "business",
 "date": "01/10/2011",
 "city": "New York"
 },
 {
 "category": "holidays",
 "date": "02/10/2011",
 "city": "New York"
 },
 {
 "category": "business",
 "date": "03/10/2011",
 "city": "New York"
 },
 {
 "category": "family",
 "date": "03/10/2011",
 "city": "New York"
 },
 {
 "category": "holidays",
 "date": "01/10/2011",
 "city": "San Francisco"
 },
 {
 "category": "family",
 "date": "02/10/2011",
 "city": "San Francisco"
 },
 {
 "category": "holidays",
 "date": "03/10/2011",
 "city": "San Francisco"
 },
 {
 "category": "family",
 "date": "01/10/2011",
 "city": "Austin"
 },
 {
 "category": "holidays",
 "date": "02/10/2011",
 "city": "Austin"
 },
 {
 "category": "family",
 "date": "03/10/2011",
 "city": "Austin"
 }
 ]
```

And I replace this code of the original code of link.

```
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
.domain([-.05, .05])
.range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));
```

by

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

and

```
d3.csv("dji.csv", function(error, csv) {
var data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
.rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
.map(csv);

rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
.select("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });
 });
```

by

```
d3.json("data3.json", function(error, data) {

alert(data);
rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data); })
    .select("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + d.city; });
});
```

But this does not show the text and also does not paint the color. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of creating a new `gist` of what I think you're after, but there's still some issues for you to resolve.  You can take a look at: http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/b237f16dda3125423130

The issue you've got is, there are multiple entries in your data for each date.  I'm assuming that this is just sample data, so it may not be a problem for your final use case, but you're going to need to decide how best to deal with this situation.  For now, I'm just referencing the first entry for each date in the code.

Key things I've done:

1. Created a nested version of your data, as per the original example.
2. Added a `domain` to the color scale using your categories as the key.
3. Parsed the date in your data to match what is used by the original example.
4. Changed the `rect.attr` to `rect.style` to set the fill color.  The `color` scale will directly return the the hex color value, rather than a class name like the original example.
5. Updated the various bits to support the new `nest` object, rather than referencing the data (which is in the wrong format) incorrectly.
6. Changed the years so you can see the values now (Your days of interest are in 2011, the original only went up to 2010).

If you check out the revisions on the underlying `gist` you'll see the changes that I've made.  They're not too complex.